# Android onOptionsItemSelected open a new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currently have an ActionBar with tabs and an OptionsMenu.  My tabs open each fragment properly but I can't quite figure out how to use onOptionsItemSelected to open a fragment.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_info) {
            new ParentInfoSectionFragement();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_history){
            new NotificationHistorySectionFragment();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

That is what I tried and is obviously wrong.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.  Thank you

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.parentprojectmobile.MainActivity" />
```

fragment_history.xml

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.parentprojectmobile.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/history_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_history" />

/RelativeLayout>
```

All fragments are just copies of original fragment and only have textviews for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fragment Transaction of your activity

**example:**

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
    transaction.replace(R.id.layout_id, new ParentInfoSectionFragement(), null).commit();
```

where `R.id.layout_id` is the layout id you want to place your fragment.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I plugged in your but unfortunately when I select the menu item I get a "Unfortunately App has stopped." message

Comment: That pop up that my phone shot out was the only error information I received

Comment: @Photekk did you put the right layout id??.. from your activity layout??

Comment: Yes, for both items. R.layout.fragment_info and R.layout.fragment_history

Comment: @Photekk post the layout of your activity.

Comment: Not enough characters to post the .xml.  It's built off of the ADT generated code Navigation Type "Action Bar Tabs(with ViewPager)".  The fragments are just Copies of fragment_main.xml withonly a textview.

Comment: @Photekk yes that one post the content of it in your post

Comment: I keep pressing enter here and it finishes the post before I am ready.  I edited my previous response to explain my activity_main and fragments

Comment: @Photekk edit your post and add your activity_main there

Comment: Definitaly does not likes .xml being posted into "``" had to take out "<" just to get the fragment_history to even show

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle your fragment stack

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_info) {
        new ParentInfoSectionFragement();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_history){
        new NotificationHistorySectionFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        notificationHistorySectionFragment = new NotificationHistorySectionFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, notificationHistorySectionFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        //Commit Transaction
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In this example `R.id.fragment_container` is the ID of your fragment container in your layout.

Comment: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager" is the error i'm getting from `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();`

Comment: Ah, well it was not stated that you were using the support fragment manager, I will update code, pretty simple changes. I made the change, all you need to change is `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: My apologies about not stating that. Still quite new to this and didn't realize.  I made the necessary changes.  Now when I select the item from the options menu I get "Unfortunately, <app name> has stopped"